# Multi criteria objective optimization function that output single solution for each variable?

Tags: matlab, optimization, methods

I am trying to make a matlab program that optimize a flexure hinge designs. As i research matlab functions for multicriteria objectives i found multiple functions such as gamultiobj, fgoalattain and paretosearch however most of them outputed arrays of result instead of outputing 1 result. however i am looking for function that just output 1 single result for each variables. So i am trying to use fmincon function but since they only except single function to optimize. So i tried to look for ways to combine multiple objective criteria function. I have found a weighted sum method to combine it(for example f(x) = w1 * f1(x) + w2 * f2(x)  ;)  i have tried fmimax as well however it always weighted towards f1(first objective function in the function array) even though f2 can still be reduced. I am hoping to weight between those 2 objective funtion 50/50 compromise.

So basically i am just looking for functions or methods for nonlinear multicriteria objective with non linear constraint problem that when given functions that give single solution that each objective compromise so that none of the objectivebeing prioritize above others (aside from weighted sum method) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this problem, but I suspect none will do exactly what you're looking for.

When you have more than one objective, and assuming the are competing, then there exists a trade-off. You need to decide the balance that you prefer between `f1` and `f2`.

Multi-objective optimization, which you mention, provides you with a Pareto-optimal set of solutions. These solutions will be what is called non-dominated, no solution in the set will be better than another both in terms of `f1` and `f2`. Each solution will represent a different trade-off between these values. It is up to you to look at the resulting set and decide which particular trade-off works best for your particular application.

As you've already found you can also do a weighted sum of objectives, converting this to a single-objective problem. However, this requires you do know your desired trade-off between the objectives and weight them accordingly. If you have some baseline solution you are trying to improve you might use that to normalize your function. For example, `f = f1/f10 + f2/f20`, would give an even balance to improving `f1` and `f2` relative to your initial design.

A third alternative is to convert one objective to a constraint. For example, if you will be happy with any solution that has `f1 < c`, for example, you can set this as a constraint and then use only `f2` as an objective.

Each of these methods require that **you** determine the trade-off, or some satisfactory value, for `f1` and `f2`. No optimization algorithms can come up with that balance for you.

Comment: Would the third alternative works for 3 objective optimization for example min f1(x) than input both f2(x) and f3(x) in the constraint?

Comment: Yes, you can extend this to as many objectives as desired by creating multiple constraints. Just keep in mind that your optimal solution will most likely be at the constraint boundary. If you set `f1 < c` as a constraint your solution will probably be at `f1 ~= c`, assuming that it finds a feasible solution.